# Python script for getting sections contents from a markdown document

Tags: python, split, markdown

I try to write a script in python for dividing contents within sections in one markdown document. For example, in

```
# Section 1

Hello

# Section 2

Bla la dsds

# Section 3 #

Ssss

## Subsection ##

aaaa
```

I want to get:

```
contents = ['# Section 1\n\nHello\n', '# Section 2\n\nBla la dsds\n', '# Section 3 #\n\nSsss\n\n## Subsection ##\n\naaaa']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Hint: `itertools.groupby(your_text.splitlines(), lambda line: line.startswith('# '))` or  `itertools.groupby(your_text.splitlines(), operator.methodcaller('startswith', '# '))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_sections(s):
    for sec in s.split('\n# '):
        yield sec if sec.startswith('# ') else '# '+sec

contents = """# Section 1

Hello

# Section 2

Bla la dsds

# Section 3 #

Ssss

## Subsection ##

aaaa"""

for i,sec in enumerate(get_sections(contents)):
    print(i,sec)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very knowledgeable about Markdown, but I'll give it a shot.

A markdown file is just a txt file, so you can load it like thus:

```
file = open('markdownfile.md','r')
data = file.read()
file.close()
```

It looks like the common factor in where you want to split is `"\n#"`, but also not followed but another `"#"` or just not `"\n##"`

So one way I can see to do this is to split the file by `"\n#"` then fix the subsections:

```
splitData = data.split("\n#")
for i in xrange(len(splitData)-1,-1,-1):#going backwards
    if splitData[i][0] == '#':#subsection
        splitData[i-1] += '\n#'+splitData.pop(i)#being sure to add back what we remove from the .split
    else:#section
        splitData[i] = '#'+splitData[i]#adding back the wanted part removed with the .split
```

or you could loop through the characters and do a manual split

```
contents = []
for i in xrange(len(data)-1-3,-1,-1):
    if data[i:i+2] == '\n#' and data[i:i+3] != '\n##'
        contents.append(data[i+1:])#append the section
        data = data[:i]#remove from data
contents.reverse()
```

I hope this helped.

**EDIT:**  You cannot just split `data` by `"\n# "` (with the space at the end) because (through my research) the space does not have to be there, for it to be recognized as a section header. (e.g. `#Section 1` would still work)